# How to use text area on change event and class object variables?

Tags: typescript, class, this, dom-events

I have an object of class `TextManager`, it has some number `xx` which is set initially to zero in the constructor.
I want to be able to update the object's `xx` variable whenever the text area changes.

```
class Drawer {
    canvasElement: HTMLCanvasElement;
    constructor(_canvasElement: HTMLCanvasElement) {
        this.canvasElement = _canvasElement;
    }
    drawCircle(x:number,y:number,radius:number,color:string) {
        var ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

var canv;
var drawer;
var d = 0;
var textAreaElement;
var textManager;

class TextManager{
    textAreaElement: HTMLAreaElement;
    xx: number;
    constructor(_textAreaElement: HTMLAreaElement) {
        this.textAreaElement = _textAreaElement;
        this.xx = 0;
        this.textAreaElement.onchange = this.update;
    }

    update() {
        this.xx += 10;
        if (this.xx > 50) this.xx = 0;
        drawer.drawCircle(95 + this.xx, 50, 40, "#FF0000");

    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    canv =  <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    drawer = new Drawer(canv);
    textAreaElement = <HTMLAreaElement>document.getElementById("codeArea");
    textManager = new TextManager(textAreaElement);
};
```

The problem is that using this way in the code results in `xx = NaN`. As i think it's not accessing the member, it's just accessing the function inside the class.

How can i update the object's `xx` with each event occurrence ?

Comment: A video on `this` in TypeScript classes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the `this` value that you want in the `update` method. Easiest fix would be to change

```
this.textAreaElement.onchange = this.update;
```

to

```
this.textAreaElement.onchange = () => this.update();
```